# Como identificar um único ponto e legendá-lo no R

Tags: r

Estou querendo identificar e legendar um único ponto em um gráfico. Estou trabalhando com um gráfico de dispersão com um indicador no eixo y e os anos no eixo x. Minha intenção é destacar o Brasil e identificá-lo com uma legenda dentro do gráfico.

Os dados abaixo podem ser usados para ilustrar o problema:

```
pibs <- tibble::tibble(
  posicao = c(1, 2, 3, 7, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 11, 13, 14, 10, 12, 17, 15, 16, 18,
              20, 19, 21),
  pais = c("Brasil", "México", "Argentina", "Venezuela", "Colômbia",
           "Chile", "Peru", "Equador", "Cuba", "República Dominicana",
           "Uruguai", "Costa Rica", "Guatemala", "Panamá", "El Salvador",
           "Bolívia", "Paraguai", "Honduras", "Haiti", "Nicarágua",
           "Santa Lúcia"),
  valor = c(2055000, 1149000, 637700, 210100, 309200,
            277000, 215200, 102300, 93790, 75020, 58420,
            58060, 75660, 61840, 28020, 37120, 29620,
            22980, 8608, 13730, 1686)
)
```

Comment: Bem-vindo ao StackOverflow em Português! Infelizmente, esta pergunta não pode ser reproduzida por quem for tentar respondê-la. Por favor, [dê uma olhada neste link](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/824/como-criar-um-exemplo-m%c3%adnimo-reproduz%c3%advel-em-r) e veja como fazer uma pergunta reproduzível em R. Assim, as pessoas que desejarem te ajudar conseguirão fazer isto da melhor maneira possível.

Comment: Pode, por favor, **editar a pergunta** com a saída de `dput(dados)` ou, se a base for muito grande, de `dput(head(dados, 20))`? Nota: `dados` é o nome da base, por exemplo de um data.frame.

Answer (score 5):

O [`gghighlight`](https://github.com/yutannihilation/gghighlight) é um pacote sensacional para fazer isso:

Aqui vai um exemplo de como fazer com ele:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(gghighlight)

ggplot(pibs, aes(x = posicao, y = valor)) +
  geom_point(color = "blue") +
  gghighlight(pais == "Brasil", label_key = pais, unhighlighted_colour = "black")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-02-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: Ou isso. Bem mais conciso.

Answer (score 3):

Primeiro vamos criar um conjunto de dados para usar na resposta. Usei o pacote [`datapasta`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/datapasta/vignettes/how-to-datapasta.html) para copiar e colar a tabela [desta página](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lista_de_pa%C3%ADses_da_Am%C3%A9rica_Latina_por_PIB_nominal).

```r
library(tidyverse)
pibs <- tibble(
  posicao = c(1, 2, 3, 7, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 11, 13, 14, 10, 12, 17, 15, 16, 18,
              20, 19, 21),
  pais = c("Brasil", "México", "Argentina", "Venezuela", "Colômbia",
           "Chile", "Peru", "Equador", "Cuba", "República Dominicana",
           "Uruguai", "Costa Rica", "Guatemala", "Panamá", "El Salvador",
           "Bolívia", "Paraguai", "Honduras", "Haiti", "Nicarágua",
           "Santa Lúcia"),
  valor = c(2055000, 1149000, 637700, 210100, 309200,
            277000, 215200, 102300, 93790, 75020, 58420,
            58060, 75660, 61840, 28020, 37120, 29620,
            22980, 8608, 13730, 1686)
)

pibs
#> # A tibble: 21 x 3
#>    posicao pais                   valor
#>      <dbl> <chr>                  <dbl>
#>  1       1 Brasil               2055000
#>  2       2 México               1149000
#>  3       3 Argentina             637700
#>  4       7 Venezuela             210100
#>  5       4 Colômbia              309200
#>  6       5 Chile                 277000
#>  7       6 Peru                  215200
#>  8       8 Equador               102300
#>  9       9 Cuba                   93790
#> 10      11 República Dominicana   75020
#> # ... with 11 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2019-02-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

A forma com a qual o [ggplot2](/questions/tagged/ggplot2) trabalha é que deve haver uma coluna na tabela indicando quais países mostrar. Podemos fazer isso assim:

```r
pibs2 <- pibs %>% 
  mutate(mostrar = pais == "Brasil")
pibs2
#> # A tibble: 21 x 4
#>    posicao pais                   valor mostrar
#>      <dbl> <chr>                  <dbl> <lgl>  
#>  1       1 Brasil               2055000 TRUE   
#>  2       2 México               1149000 FALSE  
#>  3       3 Argentina             637700 FALSE  
#>  4       7 Venezuela             210100 FALSE  
#>  5       4 Colômbia              309200 FALSE  
#>  6       5 Chile                 277000 FALSE  
#>  7       6 Peru                  215200 FALSE  
#>  8       8 Equador               102300 FALSE  
#>  9       9 Cuba                   93790 FALSE  
#> 10      11 República Dominicana   75020 FALSE  
#> # ... with 11 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2019-02-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Agora, com a coluna em mãos é possível usá-la para alcançar o objetivo. Para destacar com a cor, basta usar a nova coluna para mapear as cores.

```r
p <- ggplot(pibs2, aes(posicao, valor, col = mostrar)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("black", "darkgreen"))

p
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-02-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

E depois disso é possível usar essa coluna para filtrar a tabela e usar apenas o registro que interessa para a camada com o texto.

```r
p + 
  geom_text(aes(label = pais), data = filter(pibs2, pais == "Brasil"),
            position = position_nudge(1)) +
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-02-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: Para tirar esse `a` *"feioso"* da legenda use `position = position_nudge(2), show.legend = FALSE`. Note a mudança do valor de `position_nudge`. De resto, voto para cima.

Comment: Não quis complicar demais a resposta (dar muita informação nova), mas vou aceitar a sugestão

Comment: Obrigado pelas respostas